# selectFirst() on javafx ListView dont select the element

Tags: javafx

i have small application to manage my tasks. I created DB(sqlite), and i store there a data.

After i log in i got dashboard scene. On dashboard scene i have implemented ObservableList which store taskList and their details. This list is updated always when i add/modify/delete tasks.

I have problem when i add/modify/delete task, when i do it the list is correctly updated but the item witch i add/modify is not selected after operation although i have that implemented.

The Main code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private static Main instance;

    public BorderPane mainBorderPane;
    private Stage primaryStage;

    public static Main getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        instance = this;
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        showDashboardScene();
    }

    private void showDashboardScene() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/dashboard.fxml"));
        mainBorderPane = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainBorderPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

DashboardController:

```
public class DashboardController {

    private ObservableList<Task> tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private ListView<Task> taskListView;

    public void initialize() throws SQLException {
        tasks = TaskData.getInstance().getTaskList();
        findListChange();
        taskListView.setItems(tasks);
        taskListView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        taskListView.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    }

    public void refreshView() {
        tasks = TaskData.getInstance().getTaskList();
        findListChange();
        taskListView.setItems(tasks);
        taskListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty();
        taskListView.getSelectionModel().selectLast();
    }

    private void findListChange() {
        this.taskListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Task>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Task> observable, Task oldValue, Task newValue) {
                if (newValue != null) {
                    Task item = taskListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

dashboard.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>

<BorderPane fx:controller="sample.DashboardController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >
    <top>
        <fx:include fx:id="mainMenu" source="/sample/menu.fxml"/>
    </top>
    <left>
        <ListView fx:id="taskListView"/>
    </left>
</BorderPane>
```

MenuController

```
public class MenuController {

    public void showDialog() throws SQLException, IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/addTask.fxml"));
        loader.load();
        AddTaskController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.showAddTaskDialog();
    }
}
```

menu.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>

<MenuBar fx:controller="sample.MenuController" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
         xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml ">
    <Menu text="Tasks">
        <MenuItem text="Add" onAction="#showDialog"/>
    </Menu>

</MenuBar>
```

addTask.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<DialogPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="sample.AddTaskController">
    <content>
        <GridPane vgap="10" hgap="10" >
            <Label text="Name" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
            <TextField fx:id="taskNameTF" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
        </GridPane>
    </content>
</DialogPane>
```

AddTaskController:

```
public class AddTaskController {

    @FXML
    private TextField taskNameTF;

    @FXML
    public void showAddTaskDialog()throws IOException, SQLException {
        Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.initOwner(Main.getInstance().mainBorderPane.getScene().getWindow());
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/addTask.fxml"));

        try {
            dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(loader.load());
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Nie udało sie wyświetlić panelu, prosimy spróbować później");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);

        Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();

        if(result.isPresent() && result.get().equals(ButtonType.OK)) {
            AddTaskController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.addTaskToList();

            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/dashboard.fxml"));
            fxmlLoader.load();

            DashboardController dashboardController = fxmlLoader.getController();
            dashboardController.refreshView();

            System.out.println("OK, pressed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("CANCEL, pressed");
        }
    }

    private void addTaskToList() {
        String taskName = taskNameTF.getText().trim();
        TaskData.getInstance().addTaskToList(new Task(taskName));
    }
}
```

Task

```
public class Task {

    private String taskName;

    public Task(String taskName) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return taskName.toString();
    }
}
```

TaskData

```
public class TaskData {

    private ObservableList<Task> tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private static TaskData instance = new TaskData();

    public static TaskData getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public ObservableList<Task> getTaskList() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void addTaskToList(Task task) {
        instance.tasks.add(task);
    }
}
```

i'm not sure but when i initialize a application, reference to ListView is different than reference of list when i add/modify item. I think this is the problem but i dont know how to fix it ;/

Comment: Please include your `TaskDataProcessing` class. Or, better yet, a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: i added files for addNewTask process

Comment: you misunderstood the help page: dont show all your real code, but an extracted example - written just for demonstrating the problem

Comment: i move code to new app.

Comment: getting better :) Now throw out all the dialog/menu stuff - try to reproduce the same error f.i. by a simple button on the DashBoardController.

Comment: but if i use only dashboardController its ok, its work correctly. Problem start when i have few controllers and i want select item after add task in dialog. Thats why i paste all controllers. I think there is somthink with ListView reference because when i initilize list there is diffrent reference than when i add new task.

Comment: so you know where the error is hidden - check every single controller, try to isolate the one that produces the error (it's called debugging ;) And remove all static references ... they are bound to get you into trouble.

Comment: i know what is debugger :) i dont know how get correct controller in java FX. I tried to object DashboardController ascribe the controller from dashboard but i get wrong reference.  i used FXMLoader methods to do that but isnt work. Can you explain how in java fx i should invoke metohods from other controllers? In java fx its need to do that in special way?

Comment: i tried and no idea why this is not work ;/ Can anyone look why the rekord don't select?